# Помогите, видимо строку не могу в json

Tags: python

ответ должен получиться 0ab453458f43170f1faa9ee45d421460

```
from array import array
import hashlib
import json
secret = "212132"
app_id = "sdfsdfsdf"
nonce = "test"
params_string = json.dumps(array("app_id" ,[app_id], "nonce" , [nonce] ))
sign = hashlib.md5(params_string , secret)
print(sign )
```

Comment: а что получается?

Comment: Этот код не работает.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy я знаю что вы написали ваш код из кода на php. Предоставте источник от куда вы взяли код на php. Как я понял это API.

Comment: @СергейШашко, не то окно. :) А догадка про PHP - отличная.

Comment: @СергейШашко
<?php
    $secret = "фыафыа";
    $app_id = "фыафыа";
    $nonce = "test";
    $params_string = json_encode(array("app_id" => $app_id, "nonce" => $nonce ));

$sign = MD5($params_string . $secret);
echo ($sign );
?>

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy
<?php
    $secret = "фыафыа";
    $app_id = "фыафыа";
    $nonce = "test";
    $params_string = json_encode(array("app_id" => $app_id, "nonce" => $nonce ));

$sign = MD5($params_string . $secret);
echo ($sign );
?>

Answer (score 1):

Понадобилось сделать JSON без пробелов. Все остальные правки очевидны.

```
import hashlib
import json

secret = "фыафыа"
app_id = "фыафыа"
nonce = "test"
params_string = json.dumps(
    {"app_id": app_id, "nonce": nonce},
    separators=(',', ':')
)
print(params_string)
sign = hashlib.md5((params_string + secret).encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
print(sign)
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Пожалуйста. Рекомендую вам удалить вопрос - он плохо сформулирован, был мне интересен как головоломка, и совсем бесполезен для других пользователей.